# r Does X (time-vector a) happen in Y(time-vector b)

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have gotten some complicated time-data I am stumped at how to work with.

Basically I just want to generate a dummy-variable that is TRUE = 1, when time-vector A lies inside time-vector B. However, my data is kinda tricky, and I am not sure how to see if you can even test if something happens inside a fixed time-slot.

I have placed some data in my drop-box - hope thats okay.

```
require(repmis) # For data-download

URL <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4877253/example.csv"
df <- repmis::source_data(URL, sep = ";", header = TRUE)
```

So, what I want to do, is check if the event, a1 (date) & a2  (hour:minut) =A occurs in the interval b1 (date) & b2 (half-hour-interval) = B.

So far i've tried variations of:

```
A <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$a1_time, df$a2_time, sep = " "), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "")
B <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$b1_time, df$b2_time, sep = " "), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M-%H:%M", tz = "")
A %in% B
```

This doesn't really work, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. There will be better ways, I think. But this is working. Your data frame is called `df` here. The major work was to create two time stamps with `b1_time` and `b2_time` (i.e., `b1` and `b2`). Then, I checked if `a` stays between `b1` and `b2` in a row-wise way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.character)) %>% # convert all columns to character
    unite(a, a1_time, a2_time, sep = " ") %>% # combine a1_time and a2_time
    separate(b2_time, c("time1", "time2"), sep = "-") %>%
    unite(b1, b1_time, time1, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
    unite(b2, b1_time, time2, sep = " ") %>%
    select(-time1) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.POSIXct(strptime(., "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))), - dummy) %>% #create date objects
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(check = ifelse(between(a, b1, b2), 1, 0)) # if a stays between b1 and b2, 1. Otherwise 0.
```

Here is a part of the outcome.

```
#   dummy                   a                  b1                  b2 check
#33     0 2013-11-28 14:55:00 2013-11-28 14:00:00 2013-11-28 14:29:00     0
#34     1 2013-11-28 14:55:00 2013-11-28 14:30:00 2013-11-28 14:59:00     1
#35     0 2013-11-28 14:55:00 2013-11-28 15:00:00 2013-11-28 15:29:00     0
#36     0 2013-11-28 14:55:00 2013-11-28 15:30:00 2013-11-28 15:59:00     0
#37     0 2013-11-28 14:55:00 2013-11-28 16:00:00 2013-11-28 16:29:00     0
```